# Dynamic html links from DB are 'corrupted' by string?

Tags: php, html

I'm creating an email template.
Basically, almost all is working well. I send list of links to the user.
The problem is that somtimes, the link will be corrupted with " " (a single space) in a specific place in the href attribute.

for example - this link:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?task=quickSearchModule&job_id=40
```

turns to:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/index.php?task=quic%20kSearchModule&job_id=40
```

I managed to find out that this (seems) to be related to the text between the <a> and the </a> tags, by putting a constant inside in all links, the problematic links got fixed...

I tried to filter the variable holding the link for " " and "%20" but it didn't help - it seems to be bad rendering in the email client rather than somthing simple in the string itself.

I tried to filter the text itself between the <a> tags for bad characters (not that I see any) - didn't work (tried html_entity_decode, preg_replace of weird chars and some more) - nothing.

and to make it even weirder, in the browser the same link works, but in the email client (both Gmail and Outlook) - thats where the problem appears...

I'm running out of ideas, would really appriciate and new direction...

My system is MySQL, PHP, and of course HTML.

Thanks!

*** edit ***

I added the code I use to return each job (each link is a job).
I added some filters to it and left it to show what I tried...

```
function getJobLink($job) {
$jobTitle = strip_tags($job['job_title']);
$invalid_characters = array("$", "%", "#", "<", ">", "|", "\\", '"', "'","",'"',"/");
$jobTitle = str_replace($invalid_characters, "", $jobTitle);
$jobTitle = htmlspecialchars_decode($jobTitle);
$jobTitle=strip_tags($jobTitle);
strstr($jobTitle,'/','');
strstr($jobTitle,'<  /td>','');
strstr($jobTitle,'&lt; /td&gt;','');

strstr($jobTitle,'"','');
strstr($jobTitle,'\\','');
strstr($jobTitle,"'",'');

$jobTitle = html_entity_decode($jobTitle);
//generate link and try to filter it 
$jobLink = 'http://www.mysite.com/index.php?task=quickSearchModule&amp;job_id='.$job['jid'];
$jobLink = str_replace(' ','',$jobLink);
$jobLink = str_replace('%20','',$jobLink);
$jobLink = trim($jobLink);

//create single job HTML link and text
$job = '<tr><td style="border: 1px #cccccc solid">'.$job['field_name'].'</td><td style="border: 1px #cccccc solid">'.$job['area_name'].'</td><td style="border: 1px #cccccc solid;">'.$job['position_name'].' - <a style="" href="'.$jobLink.'" target="_blank">'.trim($jobTitle).'</a></td></tr>'; 
return $job;
```

}

Thanks again

Comment: Can you show code that generates the links?

Comment: Please add some code to get us started!

Comment: Hi, my bad - added the code. There are many filter I triend (html tags and specific characters I thought might brake the HTML...)